# How to list a page tree?

Tags: pages, child-pages

I have this structure for example:

```
Page 1
  Sub-Page 1.1
    Sub-Page 1.1.1
    Sub-Page 1.1.2
    Sub-Page 1.1.3
  Sub-Page 1.2
    Sub-Page 1.2.1
    Sub-Page 1.2.2
    Sub-Page 1.2.3
Page 2
  Sub-Page 2.1
    Sub-Page 2.1.1
    Sub-Page 2.1.2
    Sub-Page 2.1.3
  Sub-Page 2.2
    Sub-Page 2.2.1
    Sub-Page 2.2.2
    Sub-Page 2.2.3
```

I would like to have a sidebar navigation which has all items from the root-page and the curent page should be marked with some css-class. For example I'm on Page 2.2.2, the navigation should look like this:

```
Sub-Page 2.1
  Sub-Page 2.1.1
  Sub-Page 2.1.2
  Sub-Page 2.1.3
Sub-Page 2.2
  Sub-Page 2.2.1
  Sub-Page 2.2.2.current_page
  Sub-Page 2.2.3
```

Second Example: I'm on Page 1.2:

```
Sub-Page 1.1
  Sub-Page 1.1.1
  Sub-Page 1.1.2
  Sub-Page 1.1.3
Sub-Page 1.2.current_page
  Sub-Page 1.2.1
  Sub-Page 1.2.2
  Sub-Page 1.2.3
```

I looked through the codex but I could not find anything which fits. Any Ideas?

Comment: If the answer satisfies your Question, don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the tick mark on the left to the Answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

[`wp_list_pages`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages) will output all of the pages, posts, and CPTs that you wish. You even have control over the CSS classes, some of which are already there:

> All list items (li) generated by wp_list_pages() are marked with the class page_item. When wp_list_pages() is called while displaying a Page, the list item for that Page is given the additional class current_page_item.